# Can Dual Citizen Use Second Passport for Entry Stamps

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

A person has dual citizenship of country A and B. He wants to travel to country C which is visa free for citizens of country B but not A. He has valid unexpired passports for countries A and B however the passport for country B is full with no space for additional entry stamps.

https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/switzerland-and-liechtenstein.html

> PASSPORT VALIDITY 6 months required
>
> BLANK PASSPORT PAGES: 1 page
>
> TOURIST VISA REQUIRED: Not required for stays of less than 90 days

Will he be allowed to travel and at the port of entry the entry stamp placed in the passport for country A which has blank pages?

Comment: Probably not. I don't think you can stamp a passport other than the one you are using to seek entry into the country.

Comment: Are we assuming the landing country is the USA here?

Comment: @GayotFow I think we're assuming that the landing country (country C) is Switzerland or Liechtenstein, given that the quoted entry requirements are purported to be those of Switzerland and Liechtenstein.

Comment: Most western countries don't care about free or used pages and just stamp where they feel like (if at all); sometimes forty stamps on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The US Department of State doesn't really do a good job of describing other countries' entry requirements.  A better source is the Swiss government itself, which [makes no mention of blank passport pages](https://www.ch.ch/en/short-term-stays-switzerland/).

Furthermore, the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32006R0562), which discusses stamping of passports, says nothing about blank pages.

The chance of getting a passport stamp in the passport of country A is virtually nil.  Far more likely, the officer will put the stamp in the margins of the country B passport, or overlapping other stamps.  Image searches show that this practice is quite common.

The safest thing to do in this case is to get a new passport for country B.

Comment: Yes, do not bother with country A passport. Look at my old passport, at the end not only did the stamps overlap but they were stamping over the visa itself making the stamp practically unreadable. https://goo.gl/photos/BcTELScRuZvhDqk27